# Simplifying $\sum_{y\in\mathbb{N^*}}\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}$

Tags: summation, factorial

I'm looking for a way to simplify the following sum: $$\sum_{y\in\mathbb{N^*}}\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}$$

I've looked up online for some properties that may help like $$(x+y+1)!=(x+1)!(x+y)!$$ but I'm not sure if it's true or not.

Comment: $(3+3+1)! \neq (3+1)!(3+3)!$ since $7!\neq 24\cdot 6!$, so $(x+y+1)!=(x+1)!(x+y)!$ is definitely not true in general.

Comment: In fact it is only true when $y=(x+1)(x!-1)$

Comment: Your sum is nicer starting from $y=0$ rather than $y=1$.  Try it with different values of $x$

Comment: Have you tried doing this for small values of $x$? For instance, if $x=0$, then you get $\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3}+\dots$ which clearly diverges. If $x=1$, you will be able to get a telescoping sum that simplifies to $\tfrac{1}{2}$. Try to see what happens when $x=2$ and try to see if you can do some telescoping trick there. As a hint, try to find numbers $a,b,c$ such that $\tfrac{a}{n}+\tfrac{b}{n+1}+\tfrac{c}{n+2}=\tfrac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$. Update your post once you've done this and present your findings and ideas.

Comment: Is there any reason you'd expect this to have a closed form?

Comment: It can ne written as $$\frac1{x+1}\sum_{y} \frac1{\binom{x+y+1}{x+1}}$$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: with $y$ being a non-negative integer, we have that the right hand side can be related to the Beta function as $$\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}=B(x+1,y+1)\,.$$ Might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here we use a formula for reciprocal binomial coefficients
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}^{-1}=(n+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{n-k}dz\tag{1}
\end{align*}
which is based upon the *[beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{y\in\mathbb{N^*}}}\color{blue}{\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}}
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+y+1}\binom{x+y}{y}^{-1}\\
&=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^1z^y(1-z)^{x}\,dz\tag{$\to (1)$}\\
&=\int_{0}^1(1-z)^x\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}z^y\,dz\\
&=\int_{0}^1(1-z)^x\frac{1}{1-z}\,dz\\
&=\int_{0}^1(1-z)^{x-1}\,dz\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Another identity gives a shorter calculation:$$\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}=\int_0^1z^x(1-z)^ydz.$$

Comment: @J.G.: You're right. It's the identity for $\frac{1}{x+y+1}\binom{x+y}{y}^{-1}$ and it is a considerable simplification. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{y \in \mathbb{N}^+} \frac{x! y!}{(x+y+1)!} = x! \sum\limits_{y \in \mathbb{N}^+} \frac{y!}{(x+y+1)!}$$

$$= x! \frac{1}{x \Gamma (x+2)} = \frac{(x-1)!}{\Gamma (x+2)} $$

$$ = \frac{(x-1)!}{(x+1)!} = \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$

Comment: This "solution" leaves out the interesting and difficult part: the proof of $\sum_{y\in \Bbb N^+}\frac{y!}{(x+y+1)!} = \frac{1}{x \Gamma(x+2)}$

Answer (score 0):

The sum $$\sum_{y=0}^n\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{(n+1)!(x-1)!}{(x+n+1)!}$$ can be proved with a straightforward induction.

Taking limits we have $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty\frac{x!y!}{(x+y+1)!}=\frac{1}{x}-(x-1)!\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(x+n+1)!}=\frac{1}{x}$$ for $x\ge 1$

Now just substract the first term, since your sum starts from $y=1$.